# Android AsyncTask [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()]

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-handler, android-looper

I've created an image upload `AsyncTask` based on a function. And after uploading, I get this error on `onPostExecute()`. I read up some StackOverflow answers on `Runnable` yet I kept getting the error over and over again despite implementing a different solution.

My code :

```
class uploadFile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------
     * --------------------------------- Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Uploading file");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------
     * --------------------------------- getting all recent articles and
     * showing them in listview
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String existingFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/mypic.png";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        String serverResponseMessage = "";
        String urlString = "http://google.info/imgupl/index.php";
        try {
            // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    existingFileName));
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                    + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // close streams
            Integer serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponseMessage,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    serverResponseCode.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

            while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
            }
            inStream.close();

        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------
     * --------------------------------- After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

My logcat :

```
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at dev.google.imageupload.MainActivity$uploadFile.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:128)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at dev.google.imageupload.MainActivity$uploadFile.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-13 22:13:32.627: E/AndroidRuntime(9554):     ... 4 more
```

EDITED after zapl's suggestion :

```
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at dev.google.imageupload.MainActivity$uploadFile.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:128)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at dev.google.imageupload.MainActivity$uploadFile.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-13 22:38:06.297: E/AndroidRuntime(11511):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: just create the `Toast` directly in `onPostExecute` since that is already executed on the UI thread. `AsyncTask`s can only be executed from the UI thread and those `onSomthing` methods will be called from the UI thread again

Comment: Remove the runOnUiThread and that caused another problem :(

Comment: Share the new problem :D . And also let me knw what do u want to do after your pic is uploaded.

Comment: I've edited my main post. Thanks ^^
Oh I think I can complete the rest of the project after that because I store the server response in a string that I can use later on. I just need to solve this error first :(

Comment: Create a handler class and use that to pass into the AsyncTask and invoke the handler... You can have a constructor in the AsyncTask with the handler as parameter and from the `doInBackground` invoke the handler with a constant value to indicate showing a toast which will run on the UI thread - much cleaner and simpler :)

Comment: This can also happen if one AsyncTask calls another AsyncTask.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You are attempting to update the UI from a background thread. Either move the toast to `onPostExecute`, which executes on the UI thread (recommended), or call `runOnUiThread`.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // runs on UI thread
    }
});
```

Comment: Correct (which is unnecessary), but you have two `Toast` calls in `doInBackground` also, which is causing the exception.

Comment: So you mean to say that I can't have a `Toast` in `doInBackground`? Sorry I'm kinda noob here :( sorry!

EDIT I think i get it. wait a moment..

Comment: You can, but they must be in `runOnUiThread` in order to be in `doInBackground`.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much (': I managed to solve the problems. By the way, I wanna know why can't I have Toast in doInBackground. I mean, while the code is running, why can't a Toast be used?

Comment: You're welcome! Toast is a UI operation, and the UI cannot be updated directly by a background thread, which is why `runOnUiThread` is needed. Please mark this as the accepted answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I'm just learning about Java! Thanks and marked!

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the solution of my problem ;)

Answer (score 8):

> at dev.shaunidiot.imageupload.MainActivity$uploadFile.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:128)

You could use the progress mechanism of `AsyncTask`s to update UI from inside `doInBackground` while the task is running:

replace

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponseMessage,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        serverResponseCode.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
```

in `doInBackground` with

```
publishProgress(serverResponseMessage, serverResponseCode.toString());
```

and add the following to your `AsyncTask` implementation

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    if (values != null) {
        for (String value : values) {
            // shows a toast for every value we get
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

You already have set `String` as progress type in `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>` so in case you want to use progress for something different you can try to use `runOnUiThread` but I don't know if that will work.

Answer (score 0):

2023, Solved this problem by calling Looper.prepare(); before creating object inside an async method.

Comment: This removes the exception, but the Toast doesn't show when I try it